# Kotlin multiline string declaration with plus sign

Tags: android, string, kotlin

We can declare string in Java like below:

```
String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE
                + "=" + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE.toString();
```

But when I try to declare similar thing in kotlin like below, it shows the error "Unresolved reference +" in android studio.

```
val selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE
                + "=" + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE.toString()
```

However if I declare it in a single line, it works fine. But as the code doesn't look good when adding such a big code in a single line, what's the kotlin way of declaring string in multiple line with plus(+) sign?

Comment: use plus() method bro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> when I try to declare similar thing in kotlin like below, it shows the
>   error "Unresolved reference +" in android studio.

Instead of

```kotlin
val selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE
                + "=" + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE.toString()
```

Try shifting the `+` sign to the first line.

```
val selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE +
            "=" + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE.toString()
```

> as the code doesn't look good when adding such a big code in a single
>   line, what's the **kotlin** way of declaring string in multiple line with
>   plus(+) sign?

You can try the `plus` method

```
val selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE
    .plus("=")
    .plus(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE)
```

or by using `String.format` method

```kotlin
val selection = String.format(
    "%s=%s",
    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE,
    MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE
)
```

Comment: why + sign sifting to first line solve the problem? have there any specific reason or its just the kotlin way?

Comment: because Kotlin does not need `;` at the end of line like Java. So, each line will be treated as separated command. You have to put `+` sign at the end of line to tell Kotlin that the current and the next line is in the same command.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @theapache64 answer, Kotlin have `$` format.

```kotlin
val mediaType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE
val mediaImage = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE

val selection = "$mediaType=$mediaImage"
```

if you want to use an expression inside `$`, use `${ }` like this

```kotlin
val selection = "${MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE}=${MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE}"
```